# Has wifi-ap module for Raspberry pi been removed?

Tags: raspberrypi

https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/stacks/network/wifi-ap/docs/basic-ap-setup

I was referring to wifi-ap documentation for raspberry pi setup. Suddenly when I am trying to refer to the document it is a page not found.

I want to know whether the module has been removed or was removed by mistake. If it has been removed I want to know what are the best alternatives for that.

Comment: If you believe it's in error, or is referred to by another page, you can raise a ticket (bug report) and it'll be looked at.  It's more likely the information was dated, or a duplicate of another page, and it was decided the other page was better (thus that page removed).  If you provide details of your problem (and OS & release details), we maybe able to help.

Comment: Thank you guiverc for the reply. I am opening the documentation in Windows OS. I am trying to on the AP mode of raspberry pi using the wifi-ap module and was checking the documentation, can you please help with the redirected URL to the documentation or suggest to me any module for raspberry mode as Access Point.

Comment: The OS & device you're accessing the page on doesn't matter, it's the Ubuntu Core release that matters.  It could be that you're trying to access material for an older release (that doesn't really make sense I know, as all Ubuntu Core releases come with 10 years of support & haven't been around 10 years yet, but it gives me some clue (I hope) in finding something useful).

Answer (score 0):

wifi-ap is snap based and the install instructions are here:-

https://snapcraft.io/install/wifi-ap/ubuntu

and this is helpful interns of setup and configuration

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/ubuntu-core-docs/wifi-ap-docs/69?_ga=2.226682013.1029611758.1615397153-1161557404.1615397153